# Python unitesting Html-test runner index out of range

Tags: python, selenium

Hi guys I'm new to automation and trying out to automate my ui and generate the HTML test report for it. I'm using Html-test runner for it. 
Please refer the following code:

```
    #invalid Password
            def test1(self):
                    rva = signUp_invalidpassword(self.driver)
                    self.assertEqual("Error : Invalid password",rva)
                    time.sleep(6)
                    # self.driver.refresh()
                    # time.sleep(10)


    #Password Mismatch
            def test2(self):
                    rvb = signUp_passwordmismatch(self.driver)
                    self.assertEqual("Error : Confirm Password is not matching",rvb)
                    time.sleep(5)



    #Signup Succesfully
            def test3(self):
                    time.sleep(5)
                    rvc = signUp(self.driver)
                    self.assertEqual("Device Monitoring and Analysis Tool",rvc)
                    time.sleep(8)


    #Default RF parameter
            def test4(self):
                    rvd = SignIn(self.driver)
                    self.assertEqual("RSRP",rvd)
                    time.sleep(5)


    #Default Zoom_level
            def test5(self):
                    rve = zoomLevel(self.driver)
                    self.assertEqual("Zoom level: 4.0",rve)
                    time.sleep(5)

    #Chance RF parameter
            def test6(self):
                    rvf = changeRF(self.driver)
                    self.assertEqual("RSRQ",rvf)
                    time.sleep(4)


    #Empty Search State
            def test7(self):
                    rvg = noState(self.driver)
                    self.assertEqual("Please enter a search term.",rvg)
                    time.sleep(4)


    #Polygon Functionality
            def test8(self):
                    rvj = polygon(self.driver)
                    self.assertEqual("CLOSE",rvj)
  if __name__=='__main__':
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='Dmat_dir'))
```

But I'm getting the following output:

```
                            Generating HTML reports... 
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/inswadhwa/PycharmProjects/automation/assertion.py", line 99, in <module>
    unittest.main(testRunner=HtmlTestRunner.HTMLTestRunner(output='Dmat_dir'))
  File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\main.py", line 95, in __init__
    self.runTests()
  File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\unittest\main.py", line 256, in runTests
    self.result = testRunner.run(self.test)
  File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\HtmlTestRunner\runner.py", line 95, in run
    result.generate_reports(self)
  File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\HtmlTestRunner\result.py", line 339, in generate_reports
    testRunner)
  File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\HtmlTestRunner\result.py", line 316, in _report_tests
    tests = self.sort_test_list(tests)
  File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\HtmlTestRunner\result.py", line 303, in sort_test_list
    return sorted(test_list, key=self.get_test_number)
  File "C:\Users\inswadhwa\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python36-32\lib\site-packages\HtmlTestRunner\result.py", line 295, in get_test_number
    test_number = int(test_name.split('_')[1])
IndexError: list index out of range

Process finished with exit code 1
```

Can any one help me with this?

Comment: Try changing names from `test1` to `test_1` for all test. See if that helps. Seems like a bug in the runner

Comment: Thanks Tarun it worked but one issue test_10 runnig prior to test_2 then everything goes in sequence,,,causing others to fail...is this because of alphabetic order unit test in python follows and how to counter it?

Comment: Name them as test_001, test_002 and so on

Comment: Yeah! It worked for me!Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Try changing the name from `test1` to `test_1` for all test. From the error it seems the runner assumes there will be `_` in the name

To control the order use test names like `test_001`, `test_002` and so on.

Also it seems HtmlTestRunner is quite basic and not a great option. So look for alternatives